# jQuery Validation Plugin: How to validate empty fields?

Tags: jquery, validation

jQuery validation plugin doesn't validate required empty fields until submit is clicked. Is there a way to validate inline?

I need these fields to validate if left empty as a user tabs through them. So the inline messages should be displayed immeadiately after tabbing out of a required field (onBlur).

```
$("form#CheckOut").validate({
    rules: {
        NameOnCard: { required: true, minlength: 2},
        CreditCardType: {required: true},
        CardNumber: {required: true, creditcard: true},
        ConfEmail: {equalTo: "#EMail" },
        FirstName: {required:true}
    },
    messages: {
        NameOnCard: "Enter the name on your card",
        CreditCardType: "Select a credit card type",
        CardNumber: {
            required: "Please enter credit card number",
            creditcard: "Not a valid credit card number"
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: It's not possible without tweaking the validate plugin.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I need the same functionality and cannot seem to find anyway to do this.

Comment: Sorry, I never did. A non-jQuery solution is http://validatious.org. It has inline validation, but the project hasn't seen too many updates, and I was hoping for an all-JQuery solution for the site I was building.

Answer (score 0):

This is a meant behaviour. Its purpose is to annoy user as little as possible.

Source: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation#A_few_things_to_look_for_when_playing_around_with_the_demo

"Before a field is marked as invalid, the validation is lazy: Before submitting the form for the first time, the user can tab through fields without getting annoying messages - he won't get bugged before he had the chance to actually enter a correct value"

Comment: Makes sense ... obviously I should had read the docs much more closely

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to do the same thing I was:
[Validate prefilled jQuery form (invalidate on first field clear, ASP.NET and unobtrustive)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6281380/validate-prefilled-jquery-form-invalidate-on-first-field-clear-asp-net-and-unob/6637401#6637401)

, I consider it to be a defect in the plug-in:
https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues/146

I edited the plug-in until I hear back. You can also force validation of individual elements to bypass the empty-field checking.

Comment: I also posted the code change I made to address my issue, into the defect ticket.