# Validate prefilled jQuery form (invalidate on first field clear, ASP.NET and unobtrustive)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I have a form that can be filled, saved, loaded and re-edited.

When it is loaded and re-edited, it probably begins its life valid. **When a field is valid upon load, I want it to invalidate immediately when it is edited contrary to rules.** That's my question in a nutshell, and I suspect this is supported by some configuration option I can't find.

Currently, it works properly (the way desired above) only after: 1) it is edited, 2) then the field loses focus while valid, 3) then is edited it again. So it takes an extra valid loss of focus to visualize errors for a pre-filled form.

If it is empty on load (such as the first visit) it should not show errors.

I'm using the following already in my framework:

- jQuery.validate (the 'approved' one, and the focus of my question)
- jQuery unobtrusive validation adapter for ASP.NET MVC 3

**I don't currently run any custom code** to activate this, since the 'unobtrusive' adapter initializes validation (but I'd be happy to, to fix this). I've tried adding 'form.valid()' on page load, but it doesn't fix the above and in fact breaks more stuff.

Thanks,
Shannon

Comment: these seem to be related, but no solution to pre-set the form to a validated state: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464281/jquery-validate-validating-a-field-on-pageload http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6277408/jquery-validate-validating-even-if-nothing-entered

Comment: any news here? seems like i'm getting the same issues. Works fine when the form isn't prefilled. Dunno if it's something that unobtrusive does with how it inits jquery.validate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've dug into the validation plug-in, and opened a ticket for what I believe is a defect.

https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues/146

Shannon

Comment: Note I also posted the code I used to resolve my issue in the defect post.

Answer (score 0):

You could try validating the form manually each time an input was changed.

```
$(":input").live("change", function(){
    form.validate();
})
```

From looking at the documentation it seems that you can't call `form.valid()` without calling `form.validate();` first.

Comment: peeking at the code, valid will call validate() rather than actually perform the typical valid() operation on the first call, if validate() has not already been called.

Comment: unfortunately, I've found that the main problem I'm having is in the logic used to determine whether or not to validate on keyup. It is supposed to prevent nuisance validation errors (hey! I just started typing, I know I haven't entered enough characters yet!!!). However, it is poorly composed and ends up appearing to be non-deterministic until you dive into the 'lastElement' logic in the code. Your suggestion resolves part of the issue, however, if run only on forms that are fully known valid, so I'll mark accept. Note, jQuery 'delegate' is probably preferred over 'live'.

Answer (score 0):

This constructor works for me:

```
$('form').validate({
    onfocusout: function(element) {
       this.element(element);
    }, ...
});
```